# Python: Parsing an XML file with several attributes in one node

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I'm still new in programming but I know some Python and am familiar with XPath and XML in general. Currently I'm working with some XML data that looks something like this:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
      <unit>
          <structure>
              <token word="Rocky" att1="noun" att2="name">Rocky</token>
              <token word="the" att1="article" att2="">the</token>
              <token word="yellow" att1="adjective" att2="color">yellow</token>
              <token word="dog" att1="noun" att2="animal">dog</token>
          </structure>
      </unit>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

Now what I need to do with this is to first find an attribute value, let's take

```
<token word="dog" att1="noun"att2="animal"</token>
```

for an instance. So in all the structures in the document I want to first find all the nodes that have **animal** as the *att2* value and THEN get all the siblings of that node into a list. Because the nodes have several attributes each, I'm trying to include each one of them into a different list, that is to say make a list out of all the attributes in the structure that has the **animal** in one of its childrens' *att2* value. For instance:

```
 listWord = [Rocky, the, yellow, dog]
 listAtt1 = [noun, article, adjective, noun]
 listAtt2 = [name, ,color, animal]
```

At the moment I'm just wondering if it's even possible. Thus far I've only managed to hit my head against the wall with the attribute structure not to mention the empty values.

Comment: Your XML is not valid, it misses a few closing > for the tokens

Comment: Your XML structure is broken, all the `<token>` tags are missing the closing `>`, maybe a copy and paste error.

Comment: THEN get all the siblings of that node into a list. => what exactly do you call a sibling ?

Comment: Are the example `listWord` `listAtt1` and `listAtt2` the lists you are trying to build ?

Comment: Whoops, yeah just forgot the closings while constructing the structure. But they are there.

Comment: Siblings as in "Rocky", "the", "yellow" and "dog", that is to say all the nodes of that parent whose one child has the value "animal" in its att2. In other words I want to find all the "animal" values from the data and then extract all the attribute information from those structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the closing token tags included, and assuming your text is contained in `test.xml`, the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot()

listWord = []
listAtt1 = []
listAtt2 = []

for child in e.iter('token'):
    listWord.append(child.attrib['word'])
    listAtt1.append(child.attrib['att1'])
    listAtt2.append(child.attrib['att2'])

print listWord
print listAtt1
print listAtt2
```

will return:

```
['Rocky', 'the', 'yellow', 'dog']
['noun', 'article', 'adjective', 'noun']
['name', '', 'color', 'animal']
```

`e.iter()` lets you iterate over `e` as the root and elements below it - we specify the tag of `token` to only return `token` elements. `child.attrib` returns a dictionary of attributes, which we append to lists.

EDIT: For the second bit of your question, I think the following will (though potentially not best practice) do what you are looking for:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot()

listWord = []
listAtt1 = []
listAtt2 = []
animal_structs =[]

for structure in e.iter('structure'):
    for child in structure.iter('token'):
        if 'att2' in child.keys():
            if child.attrib['att2'] == 'animal':
                animal_structs.append(structure)
                break

for structure in animal_structs:
    for child in structure.iter('token'):
        listWord.append(child.attrib['word'])
        listAtt1.append(child.attrib['att1'])
        listAtt2.append(child.attrib['att2'])

print listWord
print listAtt1
print listAtt2
```

We first create a list of all the `structure` elements with an `animal` child, and then return all the then attributes for each of those structures.

Comment: This looks very promising but still all I get is: if child.attrib['att2'] == 'animal':
KeyError: 'att2'

Comment: We need to check that the `token` has this key - I've edited this in.

Comment: You are correct. This works flawlessly when I test it with a short XML extract but not that much with the original XML file. Must be something wrong with that one then.

Comment: I keep getting the same key error. There is probably still some upper structure I have forgotten or some other reason it doesn't recognize the attribute att2.

Comment: You shouldn't get the same error if you've added the `if 'att2' in child.keys()` line in, so I'm a little confused here.

Comment: Can you provide a section of the original XML data that this fails for?

Comment: I cleaned the XML up. There were just a few syntax flaws but now it all works, thank you!

Comment: That's great, glad to have helped. If you click the tick by my answer, it'll mark it as correct and make it easier for other users to find

Comment: Any suggestions if I want to direct each <structure> level entity in its own list, for example each phrase of the data would then have three lists: [Rocky, the, yellow, dog], [noun, article, adjective, noun], [name, ,color, animal] AND the next structure would then have its own lists of all the attributes in stead of all of them just going into the same long lists without any borders.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here are the parts that I understand (using lxml and xpath):

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring("""<foo>
  <bar>
      <unit>
          <structure>
              <token word="Rocky" att1="noun" att2="name"></token>
              <token word="the" att1="article" att2=""></token>
              <token word="yellow" att1="adjective" att2="color"></token>
              <token word="dog" att1="noun" att2="animal"></token>
          </structure>
      </unit>
  </bar>
</foo>""")


// get a list of all possible words, att1, att2:
listWord = tree.xpath("//token/@word")
listAtt1 = tree.xpath("//token/@att1")
listAtt2 = tree.xpath("//token/@att2")

// get all the tokens with att2="animal"
for token in tree.xpath('//token[@att2="animal"]'):
    do_your_own_stuff()
```